How can I access the user_properties column?
Within BigQuery I have access to all the viewable columns and can query them freely, however, when using the google-cloud-bigquery library I get a google.api_core.exceptions.BadRequest: 400 Unrecognized name: user_properties error.
From what I can see, these are Unsupported field types. Is there no way to access these columns, or am I performing an incorrect query?
SQL:
SELECT user_id,
NULLIF(COUNT(CASE WHEN user_property.value.string_value = 'user_type_1' THEN 1 END), 0) as user_type_1_engagement, 
NULLIF(COUNT(CASE WHEN user_property.value.string_value = 'user_type_2' THEN 1 END), 0) as user_type_2_engagement, 
NULLIF(COUNT(CASE WHEN user_property.value.string_value = 'user_type_3' THEN 1 END), 0) as user_type_3_engagement 
FROM `<project>.analytics_<id>.events_<date>`, 
UNNEST(user_properties) AS user_property 
WHERE user_id LIKE '%<PLATFORM>%' 
AND user_property.key = 'user_role' 
GROUP BY user_id

Within BQ: Query runs and returns expected values
Within the project: The query is unable to find the column called
user_properties


I managed to get around this using a common table and better date filtering. (I believe some tables in date ranges were missing this column.)
This is the code that ended up working:
WITH user_role_extracted AS (
    SELECT
        ga4_user_data.user_id,
        (
            SELECT 
                value.string_value
            FROM UNNEST(ga4_user_data.user_properties) AS usp
            WHERE usp.key = 'user_role'
        ) AS user_role
    FROM 
        `<project>.analytics_<id>.events_*` AS ga4_user_data
    WHERE
_TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN 
FORMAT_DATE("%Y%m%d", DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)) AND
FORMAT_DATE("%Y%m%d", DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY))
)
SELECT 
    user_id,
    NULLIF(COUNT(CASE WHEN user_role = 'user_type_1' THEN 1 END), 0) as user_type_1_engagement, 
    NULLIF(COUNT(CASE WHEN user_role = 'user_type_2' THEN 1 END), 0) as user_type_2_engagement, 
    NULLIF(COUNT(CASE WHEN user_role = 'user_type_3' THEN 1 END), 0) as user_type_3_engagement 
FROM user_role_extracted
WHERE user_id LIKE '%<PLATFORM>%'
GROUP BY user_id

